# Usar htaccess para hacer las url mas amigables

Tags: php, .htaccess

Anteriormente usaba mi url de la siguiente manera

```
http://www.nombredelaweb.com/rubro.php?id=juguetes-magicos
```

Obtengo el valor de la variable asi:

```
$variable = trim($_GET["id"]);
```

Ahora me actualice y en el archivo htaccess agrege las siguientes lineas

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^rubro/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).php rubro.php?id=$1
```

Formato de mi nueva url

```
<a href='http://www.nombredelaweb.com/rubro/juguetes-magicos.php'>Ver nombre</a>
```

Obtengo el valor de la variable asi:

```
$variable = trim($_GET["id"]);
```

De esta forma consigo que mi url sea mas amigable.

**Mi pregunta: Es necesario crear una carpeta dentro de mi hosting con el nombre (rubro) y dentro de esta el archivo (juguetes-magicos.php) ya que mi web quedaria asi (www.nombredelaweb.com/rubro/juguetes-magicos.php)**

Anteriormente no era necesario ya que la variable estaba en el archivo que si existia seguido de la variable y era rubro.php?id=juguetes-magicos.

Espero que me entiendan. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no es necesario.

Si tu ruta en el .htaccess es:

```
Rewriterule ^rubro/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).php rubro.php?id=$1
```

Pues el servidor interpretará cualquier URL que cumpla con la expresión, por ejemplo:

```
www.tusitio.com/rubro/mi-rubro.php
```

como si tuviera accediendo a:

```
www.tusitio.com/rubro.php?id=mi-rubro
```

Otros ejemplo:

`www.tusitio.com/rubro/rubro007.php`  <= interpretará a =>  `www.tusitio.com/rubro.php?id=rubro007`

`www.tusitio.com/rubro/el-rubro-editado.php`  <= interpretará a =>  `www.tusitio.com/rubro.php?id=el-rubro-editado`

Y para mostrar un dato depende de la ID pasada seria asi:

```
<?php
    // Este es el archivo rublo.php que obtendrá las URL amigables

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    if( $id == 'juguetes-magicos' ){
        echo 'Estas en juguetes magicos';
    }
    elseif( $id == 'mi-rubro' ){
        echo 'Estas en mi rubro';
    }
?>
```

Siendo la URL asi:

```
www.nombredelaweb.com/rubro/juguetes-magicos.php
```

Salida:

```
Estas en juguetes magicos
```

No hay necesidad de crear carpetas. El .htaccess permite que el servidor interprete las URL amigables y pasarla al código PHP de forma que lo entienda... Espero haberte ayudado :)

Saludos!

Comment: Excelente tu respuesta, para el tema del google, es lo mismo, es decir no le daria importancia si esta creada la carpeta o no. Verdad?.

Comment: No entiendo, te refieres al SEO? Si hablas de eso, pues realmente no sé como es el funcionamiento en las búsquedas.

Comment: Si exactamente al seo me referia, de todas formas no se hay problema, ya que estoy me quedo una duda es mejor hacer el htaccess como lo mensione o dentro de estos modulos.   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^rubro/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) rubro.php?id=$1
</IfModule>